# change to visibility: hidden instead of display:none in datatable processing message

Tags: css, datatable, datatables

I want to change the `display: none` to `visibility: hidden` in processing message of `data-table`.

I am using [datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net/) `data-table`.

Comment: What is the reason you want to change this?

Comment: To avoid the glitch when the table is processing.

Comment: "the glitch"? Please explain? Do you have access to the CSS of `data-table`?

Comment: no..thats wat i am asking how to change..that..when i search any column..the table will jerk..and then shows the filtered value..i want to avoid that jerk..sry for my english..

Comment: Don't worry about your English, it's the problem I don't understand ;) Is there any possibility to set up a JSfiddle? Or some other place I can try it out?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this annoying problem. If we look at the code generated by the [Datatable](http://datatables.net/), we find that the div that appears is the following :

```
<div id="name_of_your_table_processing" class="dataTables_processing" style="display: none;">
    Your custom text
</div>
```

So you understand, we will play with the CSS class `dataTables_processing`.
The code below, tested and used by myself put the text in a 150px width div at the top and center of the datatable.

```
.dataTables_processing {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 45%;
}
```

You can adapt the code to the custom text you want to appear.